# vue component containing a whole html page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currenty trying to do something, but not sure it's even possible. 
I want to create a Vue.js component containing a whole html page (with  etc ...) and this template (page) contains itself vue component and directive.

The issue is I can't have  tag in vue template for instance

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: what did you try to include html in your template? Where did you fail? What was the error? You can always append html in a template. Bind it like <div v-html="<i>Hello World</i>"></div>

Comment: I need to include a whole page, not just a piece of HTML, for instance I need to include the main page of google.com

Comment: do you have the files as local .html files or do you actually want to display a remote page?

Comment: it's a remote page